# Why can't carboxylic acid + NaH + tert-butyl bromide react to create an ester?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, nucleophilic-substitution, esters

[image]

So, the picture I showed above asks for which reagents can form the ester product. I was wondering why D can't form it? I was thinking that first, the $\ce{NaH}$ would react with the carboxylic acid to form the basic form of the carboxylic acid (where the $\ce{-OH}$ becomes $\ce{-O^-}$). Then, the $\ce{-O^-}$ of the carboxylic acid would attack the *tert*-butyl bromide in a $\mathrm{S_N1}$ reaction where the bromide would leave first. Why is this not possible?

Also, does F not work because Fischer esterification does not occur in basic/neutral conditions?

Comment: For conditions F, all you are doing is deprotonation of the benzoic acid with a strong base. Carboxylate is a poor nucleophile because of the delocalisation of the charge. Conditions B is a much better source of tBu+ than tBu-Br.

Comment: For condition D, the carboxylate will effect E2 elimination of the tertiary bromide..